# Tailwind create global style for link Laravel 8

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-8, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire

Tailwind remove default style for link, I try to add underline to all links.

I tried

```
@layer base {
  a {
    @apply underline;
  }
```

But I have no idea where to put the code, I tried inside style tag in my layout blade html file, but its not working.

I tried

```
<style>
ul-link{
 @apply underline;
}
</style>

...
<div class="ul-link">Test</div>
```

This not working either, no underline.

but like this working

```
<div class="underline">Test</div>
```

What am I missing? Why is @apply not working? and How do I create global style?

Comment: The `@layer ...` code should be in your `resources/css/app.css` file below the tailwind imports. Run again `npm run dev` to update the compiled css and it should work.

Comment: its working, another question if I just want links in certain html page to be affected. Normally I can just use <style>, how to do it with tailwind?

Comment: Add a class to specific pages that you want this style to apply on, and than only target all links in the created class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add such configurations to [base layout](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-base-styles#using-css) in app.css or app.scss file in your project.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  a {
    @apply underline;
  }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you would like this to not apply globally, then use a class name for this.

```
  .a-line {
    @apply underline;
  }
```

This way

```
<a href="#">Text 1</a>

<a href="#" class="a-link">Text 2</a> // will have underline
```